# Mapbox directions - start point is wrong

Tags: mapbox, openstreetmap, directions

All,

I am using Mapbox to get directions between two coordinates. The coordinates represent a house (and not placed on a road). For one house, Mapbox chooses the wrong street to start, probably since there is a different street that closer to the house coordinates. So, even if the two houses are at the same street, Mapbox find longer direction via other streets (going to the back of the house).

## Example:

6123 Janey Dr, Austin, TX 78757, USA
6125 Janey Dr, Austin, TX 78757, USA
these are two houses on the same street with entrance via Janey Dr. Google Maps return a short direction of 29 meters, while Mapbox (and openstreetmap) maps 6123 Janey DR to Bullard street (at the back of the house), and return directions of 239 meters.

You can see the problem on the following links from Google Maps and OpenStreetMap:

Google Maps:
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/6123+Janey+Dr,+Austin,+TX+78757,+USA/6125+Janey+Dr,+Austin,+TX+78757,+USA/@30.3421017,-97.7516021,18z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x8644cafd0fa649b9:0x42cbef40a7951d97!2m2!1d-97.7503069!2d30.3421705!1m5!1m1!1s0x8644cafd11b7c9c1:0xe24516cd197fee0b!2m2!1d-97.750604!2d30.3422424!3e0

OpenStreetMap:
https://www.openstreetmap.org/directions?engine=fossgis_osrm_foot&route=30.34222%2C-97.75038%3B30.34221%2C-97.75056

Note - the openstreetmap converts the addresses on the example above to the coordinates on the given link. To make sure both requests (google and Mapbox) are identical, use "6123 Janey Dr, Austin, TX 78757, USA" and "6125 Janey Dr, Austin, TX 78757, USA" in openstreetmap GUI.

Please explain why this is happening and how can I make sure that the directions will start on the right street and will return the shortest path.

Thx,
Yohay

Comment: I mean, it looks like an issue with openstreetmap's routing - review https://routing.openstreetmap.de/about.html I don't think this is one you can fix yourself.

Comment: In OSM the geocoding subsystem is typically independent from the routing subsystem. That's why the router typically can't deduce the correct street from a building address. Usually this is not a big deal. You could [edit the map](https://learnosm.org/en/beginner/) and add the missing building entrances to give the router a hint. However I'm not aware of any OSM-based router which supports this either at the moment.